# How to encode react route params in path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I am working on a `reactJs` project and reading the code and facing one issue.

Following is the structure of routes

```
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={<List />} />
      <Route path={NewRelativePath} element={<New />} />
      <Route path={RouteParams.subject} element={<Details />} />
      <Route path={EditRelativePath} element={<Edit />} />
      <Route
        path={clusterSchemaSchemaDiffRelativePath}
        element={<DiffContainer />}
      />
    </Routes
```

I have an issue in this route `<Route path={RouteParams.subject} element={<Details />} />`.

`RouteParam` `subject` can contain values like `test/test` and i want them to be transformed as `test%2Ftest` basically i want the subject to be encoded.

`RouterParam` looks like below

```
export enum RouteParams {
  subject = ':subject',
}
```

I tried doing `encodeURIComponent` by making the change like this

`<Route path={encodeURIComponent(RouteParams.subject)} element={<Details />} />` but it broke things than doing anything better.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: ***Why*** are you wanting/trying to "encode" the route path? It's should be a plain path string. It's the URLs that are generally URL encoded/decoded. And AFAIK `react-router` handles this bit. This smells like an XY problem, so let's take a step back and ask what the issue is that you think encoding the route path will resolve. What's the problem you are trying to solve for?

Comment: @DrewReese as I mentioned route path can be `test/test` and when it goes to backend service i want it to go like `test%2Ftest` but i saw very flaky behaviour like sometimes it is shown in the URL like this `http://localhost:8087/abc/cde/test/test` and sometimes it is like `http://localhost:8087/abc/cde/test%2Ftest`. Not sure if this answers your question. I am also new to `reactJs`.

Comment: `react-router` is a frontend routing library, matching a URL path to a `Route` path and rendering the content. Please clarify what you mean by "when it goes to backend service...". What is *it* and what is being sent to a backend service? What does any backend service have to do with the route path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode some sort of parameters in the route you would want to encode it inside of the component, not before hand. So something like this

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/subject/:subj" element={<Details/>} />
</Routes>


function Details(){

   let {subj} = useParams();

   const encodedSubj = encodeURIComponent(subj);

   //do whatever you need to do with encodedSubj in here
}
```